# Predict a text with bag of word approach

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras, text-classification

I am trying text classification using the bag of word model. Everything works fine till I use the test set for testing and evaluation of accuracy but how we can check the class of a single statement.

I have a data frame with 2 classes labels and body.

```
cout_vect = CountVectorizer()
final_count = cout_vect.fit_transform(df['body'].values.astype('U'))

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras.utils import np_utils
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(final_count, df['label'], test_size = .3, random_state=25)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(264, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=3)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=3)

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=32)
model.evaluate(x=X_test, y=y_test, batch_size=None, verbose=1, sample_weight=None)
```

Now I want to predict this statement using my model. How to do this 
I tried converting my statement to vector using the count vectorizer but according to the bag of word approach, it is just an 8 dimension vector.

```
x = "Your account balance has been deducted for 4300"
model.predict(x, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
# First transform the sentence to bag-of-words according to the already learnt vocabulary
x = cout_vect.transform([x])

# Then send the feature vector to the predict
print(model.predict(x, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None))
```

You have not shown how you "*I tried converting my statement to vector using the count vectorizer but according to the bag of word approach, it is just an 8 dimension vector.*", but I'm guessing you did this:

```
cout_vect.fit_transform([x])
```

If you call `fit()` (or `fit_transform()`), the vectorizer will forget all the previous training and only remember the current vocab, hence you only got a feature vector of size 8, whereas your previous vector was of higher size.